# Activating "pointer-events:none" only on section of image that overlaps

Tags: html, css, pointer-events

I'm using `pointer-events:none;` on the main photograph at the top of my site http://www.onedirection.net/, to allow the user to select the navigation behind the image.

However, I'd like to let the user click on each member of the band to go to a separate page, but ONLY for the parts of the image that don't overlap into the navigation.

I'm a bit stuck with this. Can it be done?  I was thinking of using an image map, but can't get it working without the navigation becoming "less clickable".

Comment: Keep the `pointer-events: none` on the image and simply add an overlaying link part to it where needed.

Comment: It can be done, but I'm not entirely sure I can work on a 1D site at work... If this is still open later and not answered, I'll do it ;)

Comment: Heh, thanks for the replies, and everyones entitled to an opinion too! ;)  Nit, so simply add another div on top of it with the image map applied?